# iOS app crashes while opening

Tags: bug, ios-app

I'm currently based in Shanghai, China. **I have recently updated my system to iOS 9.2**, and after this, my SE app on my iPhone doesn't seem to work well.

The problem is, when my cellphone is connected to *a wifi whose condition is not very well*, Stack Exchange will almost always crash on startup, stuck in the following stage for several seconds then flashing back to main screen:

[image]

By "whose condition is not so well" I mean a wifi that is slow when connecting to foreign websites. (Due to some reasons, many wifi connections in Shanghai are in such a condition, sigh) Even when the wifi connection is so good that the app won't crash, it will still take a *much longer* time to open it. (Before iOS 9.2, it takes about 2 or 3 sec for the screen to stay in the stage shown in the image above, but now it takes about like 7 or 8, which is really an awfully long time.)

Nonetheless, when I turn my wifi off and connect my phone to 3G cellular network, or even when I simply disconnect my phone from Internet (like turn on airplane mode), the app **won't** crash and will function just as well as before iOS 9.2. (Of course when on the airplane mode I can't refresh to fetch new info but at least the app doesn't crash!) So now every time I want to browse SE I have to switch to cellular network...

I tried deleting and redownloading and reinstalling the app, but the situation doesn't get any better.

I'm sorry I don't quite know how to get the error log on my iPhone, but if you need any more specific information about this problem I can provide that for you on request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Looks like so. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers @Vim you can click the blue "I agree" button to insta-close this as duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm using my iOS app (well I'm currently on a good wifi) so I don't see the blue "I agree" button.

Comment: Ha, good point. You can click the dots menu though, open the question in Chrome, and there you'll see it. (Might have to switch to full site theme first) - saying that, it does look too much, so no big deal, it will get closed eventually.